# JSF Date Format

Tags: java, jsf

I would like to display the date like `Monday, 2012-09-24`. Which date format pattern will use in JSF? Will I need to write custom convertor to get this format.

```
<h:outputText value="#{date}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="??, yyyy-mm-dd"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: i18n? or simple english?

Comment: Note: the `type` attribute is ignored if `pattern` is specified. @Peter: the current view locale will just be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this format `EEEE, yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: `mm` stands for minutes. Please read the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class, which defines the pattern codes to be used in `f:convertDateTime`.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation. You might even learn more while reading it. Double win!

Comment: Ok, so if you want to display **"Monday, 2012-09-24"** you should use **"EEEE, yyyy-MM-dd"** :)

If you only use 'EEE' as Quoi said, you'll obtain the shortened day-of-week format ('Monday'->'Mon').